# How to get latest date from fees table and compare it to current date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables members and fees ,fees table has a foreign key memberid which is a primary key in members .
I want to get those members who have not yet paid. When a member pays there are two fields fromdate and todate and both they are datetime.
So those fields helps us to know that the member paid from which date to which date .
So I want to pull out those members whose todate is older than the current date , remember since they pay monthly I want to pull out only 
one latest todate  for each member  then I compare it with current date . Any help will be appreciated . bellow is what I have tried .

```
 select  members.name , fees.todate ,
    fees.usercode
    from members 
    INNER JOIN fees
    ON members.memberid  =  fees.memberid
    WHERE
     fees.usercode ='KMTS472895'
    AND 
    fees.todate < curdate() 
    AND 
    fees.todate = (SELECT MAX(fees.todate))
    AND 
    todate !='0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY fees.memberid
    ORDER BY fees.memberid
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `memberid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `companyid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `initials` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `datejoined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `usercode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cell2` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pic` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idnumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rank` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `branch` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Company_reg_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_of_kin` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `next_of_kin_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `patient_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medPlan` varbinary(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`),
  KEY `companyid` (`companyid`),
  CONSTRAINT `members_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`companyid`) REFERENCES `company` (`companyid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fees` (
  `feesid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feestype` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `amountpaid` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `memberid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `paidfor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `paiddate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fromdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `todate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `usercode` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `paidby` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `recieved_by` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `qty` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`feesid`),
  KEY `memberid` (`memberid`),
  KEY `companyid` (`companyid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1595 ;
```

Comment: it would help if, at a minimum, you provided the table DDL; sample data and desired results are always welcome, too; see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select  members.name , fees.todate ,
fees.usercode
from members
INNER JOIN 
(
select max(usercode) as usercode
, memberid
, max(todate) as todate
from
fees    
WHERE
 fees.usercode ='KMTS472895'
 GROUP BY fees.memberid
) as fees
on members.memberid = fees.memberid
where fees.todate < curdate()
order by members.memberid
```

Comment: I  appreciate but it did not work . it displays  nothing

Comment: Remember user code is an id for multi tenant db to Identify the client who is using the system

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add the group by in the Sub-Query. I have updated my answer.

Comment: look what it does , it take out all names and it gives them the same todate

Comment: If I understand you write

1. Each member has many rows in fees table
2. For each memberid we can have many rows in the fees table and we want the query to return only those members whose max(todate) is greater than curdate(). 
Correct?

Comment: max(todate) is less than current date . and why would we also us max(usercode) please explain to me . you understood the question so well and am glad but only this max(todate) is less than current date

Comment: max(usercode) is used because of Group By. Whenever we do grouping we must use an aggregation function for the columns that don`t appear in the group by list. In this case we can use whatever we want, like max, min, etc.

Can you please add table creation scripts to your question and also a script for populating some dummy data. It will help to understand your needs much better.

Comment: I have added it sir please check the  question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66089/discussion-between-artashes-khachatryan-and-humphrey).

Answer (score 1):

Setup tables and some sample data:

NOTE: Was having some problems with (fiddle) table names @ rextester.com so added 'X' suffix to table names to get this to work.

```
drop table if exists feesX;
drop table if exists membersX;

create table membersX
(memberid    int
,name        varchar(100));

create table feesX
(memberid    int
,usercode    varchar(30)
,fromdate    datetime
,todate      datetime);

insert into membersX (memberid, name) values
(1,'John Doe'), 
(2,'Jane Doe'), 
(3,'Curly');

insert into feesX (memberid, usercode, fromdate, todate) values
(1,'XYZ1234567','2017-07-03','2017-07-22'),
(1,'KMTS472895','2017-07-23','2017-08-25'),
(1,'KMTS472895','2017-08-26','2017-10-11'),

(2,'XYZ1234567','2017-07-16','2017-08-21'),
(2,'KMTS472895','2017-08-22','2017-09-17');
```

Proposed query:

```
-- find all members who have at least 1 matching record in fees,
-- but also no fees records with todate >= curdate():

select   m.name,
         max(f.todate) as 'todate',
         f.usercode

from     membersX  m
join     feesX f

on       m.memberid  = f.memberid
where    f.usercode  = 'KMTS472895'
and      f.todate    < curdate()
and      f.todate   != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

         -- only want members who don't have a fees record with todate >= curdate():

and      not exists(select 1
                    from   feesX f2
                    where  f2.memberid = m.memberid
                    and    f2.todate   >= curdate())

group by m.name, 
         f.usercode

union

-- add members with no record in fees (ie, have never paid)

select   m.name,
         NULL as 'todate',
         'KMTS472895' as 'usercode'

from     membersX  m

         -- no matching record in fees:

where    not exists(select 1
                    from   feesX f2
                    where  f2.memberid = m.memberid)

order by 1;
```

Results:

```
name      todate               usercode
--------- -------------------- ----------
Curly     NULL                 KMTS472895
Jane Doe  17.09.2017 00:00:00  KMTS472895
```

Here's a [rextester fiddle](http://rextester.com/PWQCH34662)

Comment: I am a bit confused its a little complex

Comment: I have updated the fees table please check it

Comment: first half of `union` uses your join criteria to find all `members` with a matching record in `fees`, and the sub-query ensures we're only interested in `members` who don't also have a matching record in `fees` with `todate >= curdate()` (ie, their latest `todate` is less than today); since a `member` may have multiple records in `fees` with `todate < today`, the `max(f.todate)` gives us the latest `todate`; the second half of the union lists members who have *never* paid a fee (it's not mentioned in your post if a `member` record can have no matching record in `fees` or if we should list it)

Comment: you explained so well , but can u please update the answer also consideringing that the user code will not be the one in the query but it will be a variable from php like where usercode ="$usercode"

Comment: 1) I don't work with php so 2) I have no idea how you're building your query in php ... prepared statement? concatenating text of query with text of $usercode? a reference to the $usercode variable?; how are you passing $usercode into your query now? (I wouldn't expect it be to any different than what you're doing now ... ???) if you need help with php building the query then I'd suggest you post a new question, something along the lines of how to pass a php variable to a SQL query

Comment: i believe your query is okay but the thing is why it shows me same date and time different people . I believe we must not user usercode in group by rather feesid or member id

Comment: *shrug* ... you haven't provided any sample data, nor the results you're getting, nor the query that's being submitted to MySQL (eg, is php submitting something other than what you expect?) ... so, it's hard to comment at this point on what you're seeing on your end